# How can you recover DMs you had with a profile that has been deleted on Twitter?

Tags: twitter, twitter-direct-message, data-recovery

So, there's this friend of mine and we used to talk through direct messages on twitter sometimes, but a little while ago this person deleted their profile and the conversation doesn't show up on my DMs. There were some messages and pictures that were send through there that I would like to recover. Is this possible? If so, how?